# Delete determinate rows in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array like this but with more rows:

```
104,206   99,557        96,667   1  33  1   120,993     0
104,708   99,189    96,641   6  14  1   123,989     65536
107,099   102,732   98,641   0  46  1   118,899     131072
104,985   101,174   98,251   5  30  2   118,445     196608
108,86    103,355   103,494  0  21  1   118,423     262144
```

I need a loop which delete all the rows when in the 4th column is a 0.

I need do this with all the rows and the result is as follows:

```
104,206   99,557    96,667  1   33  1   120,993     0
104,708   99,189    96,641  6   14  1   123,989     65536
104,985   101,174   98,251  5   30  2   118,445     196608
```

Comment: plz let us knw what have u tried....

Answer (score 2):

In a single line (using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/)):

```
data(data(:,4)==0,:) = [];
```

Example:

```
>> data = [5     8     6     0     9
           1     3     3     5     2
           4     5     6     0     8
           2     2     7     3     5];

>> data(data(:,4)==0,:) = []

data =

     1     3     3     5     2
     2     2     7     3     5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = randi(10,1000,10) -1; % random data
marks = find(data(:,4)); % find only returns non-zero elements
clean_data = data(marks,:); % return all data on row /marks/
```

Comment: You use 10 indices on a two-dimensional matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.
data is 1000x10 marks is ~= 900x1 clean_data is ~= 900x10
marks is 1d

Comment: this method is on average twice as fast as the logical indexing method above (on my machine)

Comment: `data(marks,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:)` specifies 10 indices. why? it should be `data(marks,:)`

Comment: ah, my mistake. why not just revise the submission?